# Uploading files to server using php

Tags: php, file, upload

I can successfully upload files upto 3-4 MB. But when I try to upload files greater than 4 MB, it starts upload for sometime and then shows "This webpage is not available" error. I have hosted the site in 000webhost. But in localhost, I can easily upload larger files as well. Please help me out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

(and restart apache)

Comment: I can do that in localhost. But where can I find the php.ini file as I have already hosted the site

Comment: phpinfo(); command will give you location of php.ini file. You may or you may not have access to that file. If you don't you maybe can do the same thing from control panel of your host. If not then you have to ask for help host's customer service.

Comment: You can also try to set limits from php: ini_set("upload_max_filesize","300M");
Or from .htaccess file
But most likely that would be forbidden (wont't work) too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have

1. Enough permission to upload files
2. And increased `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`

`upload_max_filesize = 40M`

`post_max_size = 40M`

**Note :**

`000webhost.com` is a free hosting site and you can't expect good speed and it would fail in most cases. If you want to see good response better try in a paid hosting or try in some free app hosters like [heroku](http://heroku.com)

**Update according to user's Comment :**

`I can do that in localhost. But where can I find the php.ini file as I have already hosted the site`

You can't find the `php.ini` in online server. But you can set it using `.htaccess` files and other few ways..

Create a `.htaccess` file and inside it have the following code, then you can achieve your need.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 40M
php_value post_max_size 40M
```

Comment: adding the file size limit to .htaccess file also did'nt solve the problem. Still the same output